# C++ - Cannot open existing serial port

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port, access-denied

I'm use the following code for opening a serial port:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include "ConsoleApplication2.h"
typedef unsigned int UI_32;     // 32-bit unsigned integer
typedef unsigned int   UI_P;  // platform dependent unsigned integer (16b on 16b platforms, 32b on 32b platforms)
HANDLE hComHandle;

bool  OpenChannel(UI_32  _u32ComPort,     // COM port 1,2,...
    UI_32  _u32BaudRate,    // baud rate
    UI_32  _u32ParityIndex) // parity index in table, depends on OS (1/2/3)
{
    char acPort[20];

    sprintf_s(acPort, sizeof(acPort), "\\\\.\\COM%d", _u32ComPort);       // i pro COM10 a vic
    hComHandle = CreateFile(acPort, GENERIC_ALL, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hComHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
//#ifdef _DEBUG
        printf("Port %d couldn't be opened: error %d\n", _u32ComPort, GetLastError());
//#endif
        return false;
    }
    /*
    if (!SetBaudRate(_u32BaudRate, _u32ParityIndex))
        return false;
    if (SetupComm(hComHandle, QUEUE_IN_LEN, QUEUE_OUT_LEN) == 0)
        return false;*/
    return true;

}  // OpenChannel

bool  CloseChannel()
{
    return (CloseHandle(hComHandle) != 0);

}  // CloseChannel



int main()
{
    bool bFound;
    for (UI_P c = 1; c <= 20; c++)
    {
        if (OpenChannel(c, 9600, 2))
        {
            printf("COM%u\n ", c);
            bFound = true;
            CloseChannel();
        };

    } // for
    scanf_s(" ");
    return 0;
}
```

Can there be a mistake somewhere? Because on most of computers, this code works fine but I discovered that the code doesn't work on two computers (Win 10, Win 7 but it works on another computer with W7 well). I get the error code 5 (Access is denied.), but I can open the port via another application (Hyperterminal). A hardware is using FTDI chip but I don't think that it is the problem. I am getting desperate a bit.

**EDIT Solution**

I have solved my problem. I changed dwDesiredAccess parameter from GENERIC_ALL to GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_EXECUTE and the code works well on every computer which I had available. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170310-00/?p=95705) is answer what is the different between GENERIC_ALL and GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_EXECUTE.

Comment: serial devices usually have `DO_EXCLUSIVE` flag. device with this flag can be opened only once. next call to `CreateFile` (before previous handle is closed) will return `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. so in your case - somebody already have opened com port handle

Comment: [only one handle to the device can be open at a time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/specifying-exclusive-access-to-device-objects)

Comment: I understand that the problem is probably that something opened the serial port before I do it but it's strange that immediately after running my code I tried to open the serial port with hyperterminal and I was successful. I suppose it is not possible to get process which uses the port, isn't it?

Comment: only one file object can opened in serial at time. no way change this. *I tried to open the serial port with hyperterminal and I was successful.* - only if previous handle was closed or he duplicate it.

Comment: Since it's possible for your application to exit without closing the handle; and it can take windows a little time to clean up resources by applications sometimes; you may find the cause of the handle being opened is one of your previously run programs if it previously worked.  You may want to make sure that on signal or exception you always end up closing the handle.

Comment: >> I suppose it is not possible to get process which uses the port, isn't it?

You can use one of resource monitor programs to see which programs hold handles to "\\\\.\\COM%d"

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov - for monitor open file handles - need first open handle for this file. but open second handle to serial device is impossible

Comment: One does not need to open a file to see who else holds it open. For example, Sysinternals Process Explorer has "Find handle or DLL" window to look through all running processes one has access to. Built-in Resource Monitor seems to be able to do that too. See: https://serverfault.com/questions/1966/how-do-you-find-what-process-is-holding-a-file-open-in-windows

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov - com port can be opened via `\Device\Serial<N>` name, but can be opened via interface name (pdo device), in this case name of file will be look like `\Device\000000xx` - need first enumerate interfaces `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT` (this is correct way to get serial name instead loop by `\\.\com<N>` and look to which device `000000xx` it mapped

Comment: I have solved my problem. I edited my question.